# Pandas prints columns in next line if table row size more than 10

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
html = 'test_result_failures.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(html)
print dfs[1].head(15)
```

Trying to print the 1st table from the html. table row size is 15, if passing 15 in head, it is printing half of the table in next line.

Output:

```
                                           Module  Passed  Failed  \
```

0                            x86 CtsAadbHostTestCases      11       0
1                     x86 CtsAbiOverrideHostTestCases       1       0
2                        x86 CtsAccelerationTestCases       6       0
3                x86 CtsAccessibilityServiceTestCases     121       0
4                       x86 CtsAccessibilityTestCases      44       0
5                      x86 CtsAccountManagerTestCases     151       0
6               x86 CtsAdminPackageInstallerTestCases       0       6
7                               x86 CtsAdminTestCases      76       1
8                          x86 CtsAlarmClockTestCases       3       0
9                          x86 CtsAndroidAppTestCases       3       0
10  x86 CtsAndroidTestMockCurrentApiSignatureTestC...       1       0
11  x86 CtsAndroidTestRunnerCurrentApiSignatureTes...       1       0
12                          x86 CtsAnimationTestCases     143       0
13  x86 CtsApacheHttpLegacyCurrentApiSignatureTest...       1       0
14                    x86 CtsAppSecurityHostTestCases     217       6

```
Total Tests  Done
```

0            11  True
1             1  True
2             6  True
3           121  True
4            44  True
5           151  True
6             6  True
7            77  True
8             3  True
9             3  True
10            1  True
11            1  True
12          143  True
13            1  True
14          223  True

Answer (score 0):

Used set_option('display.width', 200) to reset the default console size from 80 to 200.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 200)
html = 'test_result_failures.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(html)
print dfs[1].head(466)
```

Resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try calling to_string()

```
print dfs[1].head(15).to_string()
```